# Why .html() method does not load data in the element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
$.get("progress.txt", null, function(data_aj){
        if(data_aj.substr(0,14) == "<!-- MSG:: -->"){
            $("#list").html("<li>"+data_aj+"</li>");
            window.clearTimeout(timeOutId);
        }else{
            $("#list").html(data_aj);
        }
    });
```

I really have tried everything but can't figure out whats wrong. If I use `alert(data_aj);` it gives the desired output and just works fine but HTML(data_aj) just doesnt loads into a `<ul>` element `#list` using .html(). Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: What's the value of `data_aj`?

Comment: Can you include a chunk of the html code?  Are you sure `#list` is the correct id?

Comment: How does your html look?

Comment: @Felix: just some html kind of "<!-- MSG:: --> <b>...</b>"

Comment: @AndrewJackman: Yes man I am sure thats the the correct ID!

Comment: @Shubham I just thought I would ask! :p  You have no idea how many times I have beat myself up over `#thisID` and `#ThisID`!

Comment: @AndrewJackman: U were kind of right. I had mistakenly declared two elements with same ID. Logical flaw. Had me stranded for about an hour. Frustating as hell! :D

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried putting your code in a document ready, as your alert will fire fine but if your dom is not loaded then you cannot append to it. Also use .append() for lists not html

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$.get("progress.txt", null, function(data_aj){
        if(data_aj.substr(0,14) == "<!-- MSG:: -->"){
            $("#list").append("<li>"+data_aj+"</li>");
            window.clearTimeout(timeOutId);
        }else{
            $("#list").append(data_aj);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Well, Thats not the case. My code is in a JS function. The function is triggered when a user clicks something.

Comment: Cool still also try the second point using append not html as its a list

Answer (score 1):

Listen up...

[`$.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) is a shorthand for [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

So when you do this

```
$.get(uri, function(data){
    //Your functionality
});
```

You're really doing this

```
$.ajax({
    url: uri,
    type: "GET",
    success: function(data) {
        //Your functionality
    }
});
```

By default this returns the page as HTML. Or rather, by default, it first checks the MIME-type on the page, and if none is found, it returns HTML. As you are requesting a .txt file it will interpret it as a simple textfile. If you want to tell it what you would like to return (HTML), you can either do it in the MIME-type on the server page, or you could use [$.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/).

An easy way to solve this is thus doing:

```
$.get(uri, function(data) {
    //Your functionality
},
"html");
```

Which is the same as doing:

```
$.ajax({
    url: uri,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "HTML",
    success: function(data) {
        //Your functionality
    }
});
```

Also it is not a good idea to use `html()` because you are replacing the existing html inside of your `ul` element every time you want to add an additional new node.

Try making use of:

```
$('#list').append('<li>' + data_aj + '</li>');
```

Basically you can just append the `<li>` to the `<ul>` itself.

Lastly make sure your dom has already been loaded by placing all your JQuery code into the

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   //Your code...
});
```

Otherwise if your HTML is not fully loaded yet, your list might not exist yet so there is no way for JQuery to put some values into unexisting HTML.

Comment: this is nonsense http://jsfiddle.net/xr5wZ/ `html()` will work on `ul` elements. The returned mime type of the request will be `text/plain` as it is coming from a txt file - that is the issue here!

Comment: `getJSON` will result in parse errors, I have no idea why you have suggested the use of that. I am glad that you edited your original answer with my correction though.

Comment: @PhilParsons I'm not sure why you are vsing me. The reason I brought up getJSON() is because it can be useful in other cases, such as when you need to get parts of the returned html body. And it's clearly not the way to solve his problem if you take the time to read my answer.

Comment: Your wording suggests that `getJSON` is appropriate to use when requesting HTML. if it is "clearly not the way to solve this problem" then why make this suggestion?